# Adjust the word space in the itemize environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, ragged2e

[image]

As you can see, there is a too-wide space caused by the long word "AuthenticateWith". Is there any idea to introduce the hyphenation under the `{itemize}` and somehow adjust the item. I tried `\justifying` and `{ragged2e}` but neither of them works fine. Please see the code:

```
\begin{itemize}

\item The predicate \textbf{\emph{authenticateWith}} is defined to associate \textbf{Federation} and \textbf{Centre} individuals, e.g. \emph{authenticateWith}(\emph{Birmingham03}, \emph{INPDR}) refers to the fact that identity certificates issued from the centre \emph{Birmingham03} can be automatically verified by \emph{INPDR}.

\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Please post an example code that reproduces the problem. That will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The code does not reflect the text in the image

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem with this code and it didn't appear so I suggest you to test it with your LaTeX distribution. If the same problem is come back, it's probably your LaTeX version or your version of babel package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}

\begin{itemize}
\item The predicate \textbf{authenticateWidth} is defined to associate   \textbf{Federation and Centre individuals}, e.g. \textit{AuthenticateWidth(Birminghamoz, INPDR)} refers to the fact that identity certificates issued from the centre \textit{Birminghamoz} can be automatically verified by INPDR.
\end{itemize}

 \begin{itemize}
 \item The predicate \textbf{\emph{trust}} is defined to associate    \textbf{Centre} individuals, e.g. \emph{trust}(\emph{Udine02}, \emph{Berlin03}) refers to an organisational trust relation between centres \emph{Udine02} and \emph{Berlin03}.
 \end{itemize} 
 \end{minipage}
 \end{document}
```

As Ian Thompson wrote, I suggest you to send an example of your code to reproduce the problem. It would be very useful to solve your problem and to help others with the same trouble and that a typical rule adopted by professional software developers.